# Is migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio necesarry?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I've tried to import my project from Eclipse to Android Studio, but I have not found the right way to do this. It is an app which has two versions, Full and Lite, and both are based on a library-project.

Migrating this to Android Studio and that Gradle-thing is a pain in the ... toe. I've read a bunch of documents, blogs and what-not to get this done, but I do not succeed. Also spent hours importing to Android Studio...

Is there actually any need to do this migration? Will the Eclipse ADT be updated in the future? I'm not going to read a bunch of documents about how Gradle works and spend hours trying to import my application to Android Studio if developing Android-application with Eclipse is an option.

Comment: Google stated, then appears to have retracted, the phrase "the ADT Plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development"; it's reported here: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/12/08/android-studio-1-0-officially-released-eclipse-adt-longer-active-development/

Comment: Ment I had read that aswell, but could not find it in official documents today. Better take som painkillers and migrate... Just to be on the safe side...

Comment: There's information on the Android dev site for migration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should follow according to [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html):

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
2. Click Import Non-Android Studio project.
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
4. In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not
   need to specify the Gradle home.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary or even mandatory. But is it smart? Yes it is. Android Studio with Gradle and Maven are soooo powerful, that you are losing so much time using Eclipse.

Of course, you will have to pass all these painful steps, like we all did. What is Gradle? What is Maven? How do I import library? Where is my code? Why my Manifest does not work? And so on...

so I strongly advise you find a week of your time and learn new IDE by fixing all those things that will arise when you do conversion.

But in the end, you can still use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA the old way and leave learning to some other time.

Comment: So, headache and ...toepain here I come! Where is my painkillers!?! I'll start migrating as soon as possible...

Comment: Stackoverflow is considered as great painkiller :)